# Combinatorics of poker hands commentary on where went wrong

Tags: combinatorics

So I was working out some of the counts with respect to poker hands and I was curious as to where I went wrong in my thinking of the solution.

Two Pair:

My solution: $$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{11}{1} \binom{4}{1}$$

their solution:

$$\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2} \binom{44}{1}$$

Straight:

my soln:  $$\binom{8}{1}$$

their solution: $$\binom{9}{1} (4^5-4)$$

questions:

1)in the two pair what did I over count that doesn't allow me to use C(13,1)C(12,1)

2) I complrtely missed the plot on straights, how did I decompose it wrong?

3) In these sorts of choosing scenarios,  how are the sets of five cards being accounted for?  We have taken stock of the needed ranks and suits,  but does the number of cards in a hand matter?  or should I look at it as "the number of sets that can be made from our specified array"?

Comment: For the two pair: you want to consider the values of the cards in the pairs as *unordered*, so it should be 13 choose 2.  Your way is just 13*12, which treats them as ordered, which overcounts by a factor of $2$.  In other words, you treat choosing the first pair as kings and the second as jacks as being different from the first pair as jacks and the second as kings.

Comment: For straights, you counted the possible high cards wrong (forgot one of A2345 and TJQKA, probably), and forgot about suits entirely.  (There are $4^5$ ways to choose the suits for a given high card, but $4$ of them are straight flushes, so they need to be excluded.)

Comment: Actually the last step of their solution to two pair looks wrong.  Choosing any of the $48$ remaining cards could result in a full house.

Comment: made a typo. thnx for the other help though

Comment: with regards to counting the amounts of straights @mjqxxxx it stated that no flushes were allowed so I figured that the highest card that could be used could be an 8 thus only the 8 choices for my "starting card" yet the solution said 9 like yourself which would mean they must've counted the straight as well....

Comment: The no flushes being allowed is why they have the $4^5-4$ since it counts the number of ways to pick suits for each card in the straight, ignoring the four flushes. Assuming aces don't go both ways (can only be used as either less than $1$ or greater than K), you can see that there are $9$ possible straights. Just look at 234567890JQKA (or, if you prefer, A234567890JQK) and since the string has $13$ characters, and a straight needs $5$ cards, there are $9$ places you can start, since you can't start at the last $4$.

Comment: I see now,  we account for all straights including flushes with $\binom{9}{1}$, but eliminate the flushes with $4^5 - 4$